# Is there a possibility to remove unprocessed floats?

Tags: floats

At some points of the document I want to remove the unprocessed floats and simply not typeset them at all. Therefore is `\clearpage` or `\FloatBarrier` not an option, because they flush the floats. 
Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish this? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You are throwing away _your content_!

Comment: do you really want to remove them, or simply not typeset them, treating them as comments?

Comment: @JosephWright I'm creating LaTeX documents with a php-script and it automatically compiles them. My problem is, that at some points in the document I need to issue a `clearpage` command and start a new section. In this case, if there is an unprocessed float, it comes alone on a separate page. It just looks odd, and I decided to throw away the float, instead of messing up the layout.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Not necessarely remove them, just prevent them from showing up in the document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
\makeatletter
\xdef\@freelist{\@freelist\@deferlist}
\gdef\@deferlist{}
\makeatother
```

which would return all the float boxes to the free list. Although counters and references (at least) are probably not expecting you to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it does exactly what I wanted, but sadly it's also true that it messes up the references.

Comment: @DanielBak it is hard to imagine how references could avoid being messed up if you delete something that is referenced...